# SoundCloud API Add to Group 429 Error

Tags: soundcloud

Is there a limit on how ofter a user can remove and re-add their song to a group (or just the general number of connections in general), say per minute/hour/day etc... I ask as I have created a script which automatically removes and re-adds all 5 of my songs within the same 75 groups, however before 1 cycle completes I get the 429 error and seem to be blocked for the day.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a limit. The [HTTP 429 status code](http://httpstatus.es/429) indicates:

> The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time.

Comment: Just as I thought, but I cannot find anywhere that states any limits for these connections, such as 1 connection per minute. Also do different account types (free, pro, unlimited) have different limits?

Comment: @tstanniland is there any useful info in the headers or body of the response?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this sort of thing, can you help me include these headers? All I see at the moment is:

The requested URL responded with HTTP code 429.